# Div width clipped - only in Firefox for Windows

Tags: windows, html, firefox4, firefox3.6, firefox-3

I am having a problem occurring only in Firefox for Windows (although I admit I am using Browserlab to test, and crossing my fingers it is accurate!)

The test page is here: http://carolineelisa.com/rkl/index2.html

Currently in FF3-4 the grey background to the footer is not the full width of the page. Sometimes it is the width of the main left hand column above it, but sometimes wider...

I have tried giving it a width of 100%, using clear fixes, removing floats from its child divs and even the columns above it, removing scripts from the page, all with no luck.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give the footer element a `min-width` of `930px` (*which is your main contents width*) so that it does not inherit from the body.

The problem you describe only happens (in my windows and FF) when the page is re-sized and the horizontal scrollbar appears.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you so much Gaby. Although on Browserlab I cannot see if the grey bar goes across the entire page, at least I know it is not smaller than the content.